# SpeechRecognizer always recognize in english (on version 4.0.3)

Tags: android

I have a problem with Android SpeechRecognizer. It works perfectly on Android version 2.3.5 with both English (en-GB) and German (de-DE), but on version 4.0.3 it always recognizes speech in English despite the fact the specified language is German.

This is my Intent which is passed to SpeechRecognizer.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, language);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
        mContext.getPackageName());
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);

mRecognizer.startListening(intent);
```

I'm sure that variable is always good (de-DE when I want German etc.).

I've also tried to add:

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, language);
```

but it doesn't work either.

I'm also sure that German is supported by SpeechRecognizer. I'm using this BroadcastReceiver to get the list of available languages.

```
public class AndroidAvailableLanguagesChecker extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private List<String> supportedLanguages;

    public AndroidAvailableLanguagesChecker() {
        supportedLanguages = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle results = getResultExtras(true);
        if (results.containsKey(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES)) {
            supportedLanguages = results
                .getStringArrayList(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES);
        }
    }

    public List<String> getSupportedLanguages() {
        return supportedLanguages;
    }
}




// using broadcast receiver
Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(
        RecognizerIntent.ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS);
mChecker = new AndroidAvailableLanguagesChecker();
context.sendOrderedBroadcast(detailsIntent, null, mChecker, null,
        Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
```

Do anyone have an idea why this is not working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds similar to an issue I have been having. Might possibly be related to this issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=RecognitionListener&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=36679

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @AdriánPérez , I'm sorry, I do not have access to the source code now. I even do not remember if I have managed to solve it....

Answer (score 0):

It is only an assumption, not testet it now, but maybe the language has to be "de_DE" instead of "de-DE", please try it....